# CSS only show one column of a table in media

Tags: html, css

I have a normal HTML table. And I want that when I'm in a mobile phone all the colums disappear excepting the second column. How can I do this?

I saw responsible tables who merges all the columns in one, but I want the other columns to disappear. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View in fullscreen and resize the window...

This will hide all `td`'s except those that are the second child of their parent (ie: column 2):

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  td:not(:nth-child(2)) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good answer - more efficient than my own.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) to apply different styles to the column you want to disable when the resolution is smaller than a certain point

**Example**

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {

   .specialColumn {
        display:none;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Media queries will do this for you:

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 479px) {
  table tr td:nth-child(1), table tr td:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Here's a fiddle, I've used nth-child selectors to select only the 1st and third columns: https://jsfiddle.net/pqp11dqe/

Answer (score 0):

Try using media queries. 
Something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px /*max width of smaller screen*/) {
    .classOfColumnsToHide {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using media queries. But I didn't know the display:none property. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be developing and working on mobiles you'll want to look at [bootstrap css](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) It will help you immensely, and do away with a lot of the manual css coding. It will also fix your current issue and in the long run, you'll probably end up loving using it.